# Message: move_uploaded_file(): failed to open stream: Permission denied in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

my project ran well in localhost using xampp but in remote server I've got an error when Im trying to upload or update an image,..

> warning:
>   Message:  move_uploaded_file(images/1458100947_2.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

here is the code were the errors located.

```
            $imagename = $this->person->view($this->input->post('id'))->image;
     if(file_exists("images/$imagename")) unlink("images/".$imagename);
     $fileName = time(). '_' .$_FILES["image"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName); //this line
$targetPath = 'images/' . $fileName;
    $config_resize['image_library'] = 'gd2';
     $config_resize['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
     $config_resize['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
  //   $config_resize['master_dim'] = 'height';
     $config_resize['quality'] = "80%";
     $config_resize['source_image'] = $targetPath;
     $config_resize['height'] = 600;
     $config_resize['width'] = 1024;
  //   $config_resize['thumb_marker'] = '';
     $config_resize['new_image'] = 'images/' . $fileName;
     $this->image_lib->initialize($config_resize);
     $this->image_lib->resize();

     $uploaded = TRUE;
```

I am trying to google on how to set the permission to 777 in codeigniter but no luck.. here is my project link http://mysports.orgfree.com. use this admin account.

> username: mak password: mak

to login and click the edit button then upload some image.. the error will show after that.. thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my permission issue by using SmartFTP to upload the files, because it provides an easy way to set the permission. This resolved my question and my code works now.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can give 2 way permission

1) directly give folder permission using this way

```
chmod("folder name with path", 755);
```

2)directly give file permission using this way and use this code after move_uploaded_file function

```
chmod("file name with path", 644);
```